# Making a system call to host "function" from C

Tags: c

I am trying to reproduce in a C program what I can do in the console. In this case, call the host command to sniff a site. My guess of why it is not working is because maybe :host is not a system function"? How can then this be achieved?

I do this at the console and it works:

```
host -t txt harvard.edu
```

But if I try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
   system(``host -t txt google.com);
    return 0;

}
```

then I get all errors. If I add the ticks, then it says "stray tick" and also it will say host is not declared, etc. If I remove them, then it just complains that host is not declared, so obviously *system* does not deal with host, but if the console does, then how can you do that from C?

Comment: How about using string quotes?

Comment: Beware of the confusing terminology. The [system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) function of the C standard library is *not* a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) provided by the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), but internally it is using several of them (e.g. `fork`, `waitpid`, `execve` on POSIX systems like Linux or MacOSX).

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the `system` function. It is just a matter of writing correctly [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) inside your C program.

Comment: You don't need to edit to say the question has been answered, that's pretty easy to notice anyway due to the design of this site. :)

Comment: This was most likely caused by a transcription error (typos when typing in code [from a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159353/making-a-system-call-to-host-function-from-c#comment71484221_42159411)). This question should never have been posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean

```
 system("host -t txt google.com");
```

You might need to specify the full path to host.

Comment: But other people are right too... Your original code do not compile, and you have not taken the time to understand the error, or just writing the error message in the question. And as you have understood, your issue is totally unrelated to `system` function (you could have made the same mistake with `popen`); it was a matter of correct lexical & syntactical practices.

Comment: No, because that syntax is a copy paste from the book of the Open Univesity UK C on Unix and it did not work as copied and pasted. So how could I know what was wrong?

Comment: By reading more [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/topics) about the C programming language. You can find several books, and also [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language) and the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft standard of C11. As a student, you are expected to be able to find that alone.

Comment: You could have known because you study C. No-one _was_ mocking you, but now we are (I am) because of your lack of any study on one of the most basic thngs of C. And by the way, if it was an ebook, then the typography used the wrong quotes, which is perfectly fine for publishing, and if you re-typed it then it was your error.

Comment: I am not a student, I am a 55 year old retired pharmacist and economist learning programming for my entertainment.

Comment: It can't have been copy paste (it wouldn't have been so inconsistently formatted if it was in a book). More like ***typed in*** from the book. The first double quote was typed as two backticks and the second wasn't typed in.